# protobuf golang import .proto and .pb.proto from different directories

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have a library called myProtos which looks like this

```
.
|-- proto
|---- hello.proto
|
|-- generated
└---- hello.pb.go
```

I have a .proto file outside called `example.proto` that should import `hello.proto`

So the top of the file looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package example;
import "path/to/myProtos/proto/hello.proto"
```

Now, when I compile `example.proto` I get an import error on `example.pb.go` because it has the import line import "path/to/myProtos/proto/hello.pb.go"

I tried adding both import paths, but I get an 'import but not used error'. I also tried doing relative imports and passing both directories as flags to protoc, which worked, but I need the import path in the go file to be absolute.

How can I tell protoc that on the go file the path is different?

Is there a better 'best practice' in this case?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is to define `option go_package = "github.com/<your-account>/<your-cool-project>/<sub-dirs>`

Let's assume you have the folder structure your stated:

```
.
|-- proto
|---- hello.proto
|
|-- generated
└---- hello.pb.go
```

In your case you would add `option go_package = "<path>/<in>/<GOPATH>/generated"` to `hello.proto`.
What is important is that you then have to run

```sh
protoc -I. --go_out=$GOPATH ./*.proto
```

Generally, I would generate the go files alongside the proto files to keep the import paths the same for proto and go files. But this might be a matter of taste. In that case you would then simply set `option go_package = "<path>/<in>/<GOPATH>/proto"` to `hello.proto`.

In both cases a relative import of the `.proto` file should now resolve to the proper import in the generated Go code and the `.pb.go` files should also be put into the proper Go package folders.

Answer (score -1):

Use `package generated;` inside your `hello.proto` file.

Then, `protoc -I proto/ proto/*.proto --go_out=generated` will generate a `hello.pb.go` inside `generated` folder by the package name of `generated`.

The package inside the proto files tells the protobuf generator which package to use inside the generated file.